# Button not triggering .ics file download

Tags: javascript, html, button

I believe the 'saveAs' function is being called correctly.

The consoles not reporting any errors. Im at a loss.

here is a link to the site [SDC](https://adamkaytr.github.io/SmartDynamicCalendar/)

The Repository [Repo](https://github.com/Adamkaytr/SmartDynamicCalendar)

I expected the .ics file to generate. I don't blatantly see anything wrong with the code unless I'm missing something.

Comment: The use of `import` syntax means your JS file must be interpreted as a module - looks like your missing a `type="module"` on your `script` tag.

Also, if you look at the network tab on the Github site you linked, `events.js` returns a 404. It looks like that might be case sensitive when served over github pages.

Comment: It also looks like your URL to icalgen might be bad.